# How to vertically align the wrapper or entire container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to vertically align the entire container or wrapper?

http://jsfiddle.net/mpt20o1y/

(widen the view so it's not narrow to see it in full)

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 mb-2 mt-4">
            <a href="/edit" class="no-decoration">
            </a><a href="/edit" class="no-decoration">
            <div class="inforide">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-8 fontsty">
                  <div class="center">
                    <div class="setting-awesome-font">
                      <i class="fas fa-user fa-1x"></i><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="setting-text">
                      <h5>Account</h5>
                      <p>Manage your account login details</p><p>
                    </p></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a></div><a href="/edit" class="no-decoration">
        </a>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 mb-2 mt-4">
            <div class="inforide">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-8 fontsty">
                  <div class="center">
                    <div class="setting-awesome-font">
                      <i class="fas fa-university fa-1x"></i><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="setting-text">
                      <h5>1 Settings</h5>
                      <p>view settings</p><p>
                    </p></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 mb-2 mt-4">
          <div class="inforide">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-8 fontsty">
                  <div class="settings">
                    <div class="center">
                      <div class="setting-awesome-font">
                        <i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar fa-1x"></i><br>
                      </div>
                      <div class="setting-text">
                        <h5>History</h5>
                        <p>View history</p><p>
                      </p></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 mb-2 mt-4">
          <div class="inforide">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-8 fontsty">
                  <div class="settings">
                    <div class="center">
                      <div class="setting-awesome-font">
                        <i class="fas fa-building fa-1x"></i><br>
                      </div>
                      <div class="setting-text">
                        <h5>Settings</h5>
                        <p>View settings</p><p>
                      </p></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see in the fiddle, all of the container aligns left.  How can I have it so the container centers?

(my customs css is not involved in the fiddle but isn't important to the situation, most of it is for text-align, coloring, decorations, etc.)

Comment: not sure what you want by that. :\
Can you be more specific?

Comment: I want the entire wrapper to be centered.  Imagine a dice on the 4 side, like that.  instead of how it is, with the 4 dots aligned left.

Comment: I think it's better if you could draw it out. I see no dots here!!!

Comment: this is how it is = [::  ] ---- This is how i want it= [ :: ]

Comment: https://screenshots.firefox.com/oQYTJtneI8V47tVL/jsfiddle.net
This is what it looks like to me

Comment: Yes, it is aligning left, not centered.  The entire wrapper i want shifted centered more towards the right

Comment: use this ```.content-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin: 10%;
}```  you can delete border, I kept only for your reference.

Comment: Still aligned to left.  Did work in the fiddle for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a container DOM element within CSS styles with following:

1. display: flex;
2. align-items: center; (vertically centered)
3. justify-content: center; (Horizontally centered)

For example:

```css
div.v-center-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 4em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="v-center-container">
<div>This is vertically center strings</div>
</div>
```

Every thing inside DOM element with class `v-center-container` will automatically vertical alignment.

Comment: I don't want to ask you to do more - and i appreciate your time but can you apply this to my fiddle and link me the results.  because bootstrap can sometimes interfere...

Comment: Add "justify-content: center" css for "container-fluid" class, try it

Comment: <div class="container-fluid" style="justify-content: center">...</div>

Comment: It worked! I applied it to the div class="row" as div class="row v-center-container" to all of the rows and it worked.... looks like the issue was the individual "blocks" as rows were aligning left

Comment: @uno Yes, the individual blocks are aligning left due to the column size. You can also remove inner grid to make it full width. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rhythm19/guwp357b/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with flex classes from Bootstrap.

Flex document: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

Example:

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-dark text-light p-5">
<div class="border border-danger p-3">centered content</div>
</div>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```